# Can a fixed amount of ideal gas undergo a reversible process when 2 of either pressure, volume, or temperature are held constant?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, ideal-gas, reversibility

I've seen some problems where this was the case: a fixed amount of ideal gas underwent a *reversible* process where temperature varied while pressure and volume were both held constant. How could that be possible? For an ideal gas, $PV=nRT$ so, if three variables are defined, then the remaining variable can only take a single value to satisfy the equation. It seems impossible to me that such process can exist, at least, with the constraints established.

Edit: For clarifying, consider this example: 1 mol of monoatomic ideal gas undergoes a reversible process from 300 K to 350 K at constant pressure and volume (which aren't specified). Heat capacity is deemed independent from temperature. One is asked to calculate the enthalpy change for this process.

Even though there are formulas such as $C_P\Delta T$ for finding heat $q$, which in turn may be used to calculate $\Delta H$ at constant pressure, the constant volume and reversibility constraints make me doubt it can be solved just like that.

Comment: it will be better if you could attach one of such problems.

Comment: One could conceptually model exposing the system to an infinite number of thermal reservoirs, each incrementally warmer than the next. This is how one models reversible heating of a system at fixed volume and pressure. If this gets at what you're asking about, I'll expand as an answer. Please clarify.

Comment: Please provide a reference for what you claim, and the specific problem this thinking was applied to.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Yes, that sounds like an appropriate way to solve the problem. As long as one can conceive a reversible process with both constant pressure and volume, it should work for this problem. Now that you mention it, I wonder how one can reversibly increase an ideal gas' temperature without changing n, P, V, or phase composition. I would be glad to read your answer.

Comment: @Rodrigo You can't increase temperature and constant pressure, volume, and particle number for an ideal gas. Either there's an issue with the source or some sort of missing context. Where did you find the example problem you quote?

Comment: @Jagerber48 The example I provided was inspired by this post on Chemistry Stack Exchange: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31917/entropy-increase-when-heating-a-gas

Comment: I want to mention that I managed to find the original exercise in the Atkins' book cited in the post and it's clear there was a misinterpretation of it. It asks for calculations for different cases: one at constant pressure and the other at constant volume. However, Chemomechanics mentioned it's possible to heat a system at constant P and V, though I don´t know the full context for that.